# Be In Hard Labor

Tags: meaning, usage

I have a question about the structure of the pattern "*sell somebody into hard labor*".  Usually if a somebody could be "*[verb in participle form] into [noun A]*",  then one can also be "*in [noun A]*".  So, back to the phrase "*sell somebody into hard labor*".  Since I can write:

> He was sold ***into hard labor***.

Does it mean I could write:

> He was ***in hard labor***.

?

Answer (score 1):

It's not common to use *hard labor* in this way. The meaning of the first sentence is clear because it plays off the common phrase *to be sold into slavery*. In general, *hard labor* and *slavery* are not interchangeable, even though their meanings are similar. You can say *in slavery* (more often *enslaved*) but *in hard labor* doesn't make sense in this context. That's partly because it collides with the usage *in labor* which refers to giving birth.